# I'm trying to make a Python procedure that converts binary numbers to decimal numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, binary, procedure

I'm trying to create a procedure out of the following code in Python:

```
print "Program for Binary to Decimal Conversion"
dec = 0`enter code here`
bin = 0
factor = 1;
print "Enter Binary Number:", 
bin = input()
while(bin > 0):
   if( (bin % 10) == 1):
      dec += factor
   bin /= 10
   factor = factor * 2
print "The Decimal Number is: ", dec
```

It currently runs in the shell asking what the input, I want to make it like a procedure so that it just runs in the python shell without asking anything and the input line would look something like:

```
procedure(1110101)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare a procedure in Python as shown [here] (http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html)

e.g. 
    def bin2dec(number):
      your code

Answer (score 0):

A function in Python is defined like so:

```
def funcname(args):
    # indented code is not optional
    # these are comments
```

For instance:

```
def bin_to_dec(binary):
    print "Program for Binary to Decimal Conversion"
    dec = 0
    factor = 1
    while(binary > 0):
       if( (binary % 10) == 1):
          dec += factor
       binary /= 10
       factor = factor * 2
    print "The Decimal Number is: ", dec
```

Now you can call that like

```
bin_to_dec(10010110)
```

I would advise doing some basic tutorials to learn Python fundamentals. The web has many.

Now check this out:

```
def bin_to_dec(binary):
    return int(binary, 2)

>>> print bin_to_dec('10000000')
128
```

Answer (score 0):

The theory behind binary to decimal conversion is that each digit represents a power of two.
so you could do something like this:
-take in the digits as a string
-iterate through the string multiplying the digit by the power of 2 it represents
like so:

```
    #ex string = 101
    def binToDec(string):
        binString = str(string).reverse() #reverse to make iteration easier sort of
        dec=0;
        place=0;
        for digit in binString:
            dec+= (int(digit))*(2**place)

        return dec
```